# Limit values of a continuous function with a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Denote $S=(0,1]\times[0,1]$ a square without the left side. Does there exist  a function $f$ smooth enough on $S$, say $f\in C^1(S)$ or $C(S)$ s.t.

I) $f$ is not bounded in any neighbourhood of any point $(0,y)$ on the left side of $S$;

II) for every $y\in[0,1]$ there exists $\lim_{x\to+0}f(x,y)=g(y)$ and $g\in C([0,1])$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there were such an $f,$ with $f$ continuous. For $m,n \in \mathbb N,$ define

$$E_{m,n} = \{y\in [0,1]: |f(x,y)| \le m \text { for } x \in (0,1/n]\}.$$

Then $[0,1] =\bigcup E_{m,n},$ and each $E_{m,n}$ is closed in $[0,1].$ By Baire, some $E_{m,n}$ contains a nonempty open interval. This violates the unboundedness hypothesis on the left edge, contradiction.